# char[] size not being counted

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct E_s {
    uint32_t    a;
    uint32_t    b;
    uint32_t    c;
} E_t;

typedef struct S_s {
    uint32_t    data_sz;
    char        data[];
} S_t;

typedef struct F_s {
    E_t     E;
    S_t     S;
    char        data[16];
//} __attribute__((packed)) full_msg_t;
} F_t;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    F_t out;
    printf("sizeof(out.data) = %lu\n", sizeof(out.data));
    printf("sizeof(out.E) = %lu\n", sizeof(E_t));
    printf("sizeof(out.S) = %lu\n", sizeof(S_t));
    printf("sizeof(out) = %lu\n", sizeof(F_t));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run the code, I see the following output:

```
sizeof(out.data) = 16
sizeof(out.E) = 12
sizeof(out.S) = 4
sizeof(out) = 32
```

**Question:** Why is the size of `S_t` 4 (third line of output)? I was expecting it to be 8 (`uint32_t` + `char[]`). Why is the size of `char[]` not included?

Furthermore, both `out.data` and `out.S.data` point to the same memory location, which caused me to dive deep and find the above observation. Any clue here will also be very helpful. I was not expecting those 2 variables to overlap.

Comment: You cannot put a structure with a flexible array member inside a structure.

Comment: "Why is size of char[] not included?" What is size of an array with 0 entries?

Comment: What did you expect `sizeof(S_t)` to be?

Comment: All the answers say that flexible array members *don't* contribute to the the size, but the it's worth nothing that such members *can't* contribute. `sizeof` always returns the same value for any given type, so it can't possibly include the size of the array since that's not part of the type.

Comment: Re "*I was expecting it to be 8 (`uint32_t + char[]`)*", `char data[]` is not a pointer. Accessing `data` allows you to access the bytes that follow the `struct S_s`. In this case, `out.S.data` is just another way of accessing `out.data`

Comment: Strictly, the format for printing `size_t` values (such as the value returned by `sizeof`) is `%zu`, the `z` being the length modifier that denotes `size_t`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard specifies that the variable part of a structure with a [flexible array member (FAM)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18) is ignored when the size is calculated:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. **In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored.** In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply. However, when a `.` (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ from that of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to generate a pointer one past it.

<sup>*Emphasis added*</sup>

Note that the `struct F_s` (aka `F_t`) should not be accepted; that violates the constraint in [§6.7.2.1 ¶3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array.

The compiler should reject that (or, at least, emit a diagnostic) because constraint violations require a diagnostic.  Even if the compiler doesn't reject it outright, you can't actually use the FAM of the embedded `S_t` because the `data` member of `F_t` doesn't move — the offsets of the elements of a structure are fixed at compile time.  It would, de facto, use the `data` element of `F_t`, but that isn't defined behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

In this struct:

```
typedef struct S_s {
    uint32_t    data_sz;
    char        data[];
} S_t;
```

The `data` member is a **flexible** array member.  Such a member does not contribute to the size of a struct as its size is not specified.  This is spelled out in section 6.7.2.1p18 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
> named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
> flexible array member. In most situations, the flexible array member
> is ignored. **In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
> flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more
> trailing padding than the omission would imply.**

So the size of `S_t` does not include the `data` member, which is why `sizeof(S_t)` is 4.

Such a member can only be used when memory for the struct is dynamically allocated.  For example:

```
S_t *s = malloc(sizeof(S_t) + 10);
```

This allows you to access from `s->data[0]` to `s->data[9]`

This also means that you can't put a struct with a flexible array member inside of another struct or in an array, because there's no way to know exactly where the flexible array member ends.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.2.1p3:

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
> function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
> itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), **except
> that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union
> containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure)
> shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array**

Answer (score 7):

`char data[];` is a flexible array member and it is explicitly guaranteed not to have its size counted. Because it is mainly supposed to be used as `malloc(sizeof(St_t) + n)`, where `n` is the size of the `data` array.

As for `S_t S;` inside the other struct, that's invalid C since the struct containing a flexible array member must be placed at the end and in the outer-most struct and you didn't do that. So your code doesn't compile in standard C and there it isn't possible to make assumptions that `out.S.data` and `out.data` are somehow the same memory, because all of that is beyond the scope of the C language. I suppose it might be possible that GNU C offers deterministic behavior in the form of non-standard extensions, but I'm not aware of any such guarantees.

Comment: GNU = GNU's Not docUmented

Comment: I cannot see anything specific in the standard that makes the `S_t S;` member invalid.

Comment: @IanAbbott — see [§6.7.2.1 ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3).  It's a constraint, so the attempt to use `S_t S;` in a structure is a constraint violation and must be diagnosed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually I had not realized that the requirement isn't just that a struct with a flexible array member has to be placed last. The constraints explicitly say that the struct cannot be member of another struct at all, no matter where it is placed.

Comment: @Lundin: the rules are both simple and strict.  I'm not aware of the forthcoming C23 standard tinkering with the rules for structures or unions containing a FAM.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the reference. At least it still seems to be possible to use a structure with a flexible array member as a member of a union (as long as that union is not a member of a structure or an element of an array), so there is still some possibility of defining objects with space reserved for the elements of the flexible array member. These constraints make sense as they avoid union-like behavior in something that isn't a union.

Answer (score 3):

Because char[] in structure S_t is called **flexible array**, which is a feature introduced in the C99 standard of the C programming language.

This maybe helpful [flexible-array-members-structure-c](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flexible-array-members-structure-c/)

Comment: Strictly, it's a flexible array member, but that's trivia.  You're right that FAMs were introduced in C99, but that isn't why the size of the FAM is treated as zero — it's because the standard says the size is treated as zero.    The linked summary says the FAM 'should preferably be declared as the last member' but the standard gives no option — it _must_ be the last member because the layout of the other members of the structure is fixed.  So, the link isn't dreadfully helpful, though there are probably worse ones on the internet.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't get why it's supposed to be the last member "because the layout of the other members of the structure is fixed"; shouldn't data structure alignment sort members regardless of what order they're written within the code? I assume this is due to supporting the general case, but that reason alone is kinda weird

Comment: @MaurizioCarcassona: the compiler may not reorder the members of a structure; they must appear in the order in which they are specified.  That's one of the reasons you can end up with padding in a structure between members and at the end.  See [§6.7.2.1 ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p6): _As discussed in [§6.2.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.72.5), a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, whose storage is allocated in an ordered sequence, and a union is a type consisting of a sequence of members whose storage overlap._

Comment: @MaurizioCarcassona: If you see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74098014/15168), you'll also see that the standard mandates that the FAM is the last element of the structure.  Part of the reason for that is that the elements of a structure are all at fixed positions within the structure so that the calculations for accessing the elements are easy.  It's also why you can't have two FAMs in one structure.  Arrays are of fixed size objects; that's why you can't have a structure with a FAM inside an array, or inside another structure (not even as the last member of another structure).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right, I should be more careful and practice English which is not my mother tongue.